# Custom Calendar widget, how to consume an event?

Tags: iccube-reporting

I've created a calendar widget like the one in the livedemo - Widget Template - Filter / Fire Event ([https://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3Report=%2Fshared%2FLive+Demo%2F3+-+How+to%2FWidget+Template+-+Filter+%252F+Event](https://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3Report=%2Fshared%2FLive%20Demo%2F3%20-%20How%20to%2FWidget%20Template%20-%20Filter%20%252F%20Event)).

Now I want to use an event from another widget e.g. a button to set the current date. I've configured the widget with the do Set Selection event in the Events configuration:
[image: Events Configuration]

But when I trigger that event by pushing the button, nothing happens and a error is shown in the notifications-box:
[image: error in the notifications-box]

The browsers console also shows an error:

> 12:32:29.929 [Widget (consumeEventHook)][w1] Unexpected identifier

What do I wrong and how do I make this work?

Comment: what is the version of the reporting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niels, sorry there is a bug in the reporting (the fix will be available in the next release). Here is an example of the on-consume-event function:

```
/**
 * type  - consumed event type,
 * event - consumed event object
 * 
 * Function may return false, to stop event processing
 */

    function(context, type, event) {
        switch(type){
            case 'ic3doSetSelection':      
                var w = $('#reportrange');
                var d = w.data('daterangepicker');            

                d.setStartDate('03/01/2016');
                d.setEndDate('03/31/2016');

                break;
       }
    }
```

Hope this helps.